# как правильно распарсить JSON глубокой вложенности, как вытащить нижний элемент

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
"_embedded" : {
"document" : [ {
  "businessId" : "18749116-1-56",
  "dateReception" : "2017-08-16T22:18:56.772+0000",
  "type" : "ARTMAG",
  "sequence" : 367,
  "replayDate" : "2017-08-18T05:23:44.362+0000",
  "rejectsNumber" : 3,
  "status" : 303,
  "errorCode" : "OPI_1001",
  "lastUpdate" : "2017-08-17T22:52:36.522+0000",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "#"
    },
    "docArtMag" : {
      "href" : "#"
    }
  }
}, {
  "businessId" : "18749116-1-79",
  "dateReception" : "2017-08-16T22:18:56.756+0000",
  "type" : "ARTMAG",
  "sequence" : 367,
  "replayDate" : "2017-08-18T05:23:44.370+0000",
  "rejectsNumber" : 3,
  "status" : 303,
  "errorCode" : "OPI_1001",
  "lastUpdate" : "2017-08-17T22:52:36.541+0000",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "#"
    },
    "docArtMag" : {
      "href" : "#"
    }
  }
} ]
  },
  "_links" : {
"first" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"self" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"next" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"last" : {
  "href" : "#"
}
  },
"page" : {
"size" : 10,
"totalElements" : 35078,
"totalPages" : 3508,
"number" : 0
}
}
```

Comment: В чём сложность, что хотите получить в итоге?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Правильно распарсить" от глубины вложенности не зависит.

```js
var data = JSON.parse($("div").text());
console.log(data.page);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
{
"_embedded" : {
"document" : [ {
  "businessId" : "18749116-1-56",
  "dateReception" : "2017-08-16T22:18:56.772+0000",
  "type" : "ARTMAG",
  "sequence" : 367,
  "replayDate" : "2017-08-18T05:23:44.362+0000",
  "rejectsNumber" : 3,
  "status" : 303,
  "errorCode" : "OPI_1001",
  "lastUpdate" : "2017-08-17T22:52:36.522+0000",
  "_links" : {
"self" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"docArtMag" : {
  "href" : "#"
}
  }
}, {
  "businessId" : "18749116-1-79",
  "dateReception" : "2017-08-16T22:18:56.756+0000",
  "type" : "ARTMAG",
  "sequence" : 367,
  "replayDate" : "2017-08-18T05:23:44.370+0000",
  "rejectsNumber" : 3,
  "status" : 303,
  "errorCode" : "OPI_1001",
  "lastUpdate" : "2017-08-17T22:52:36.541+0000",
  "_links" : {
"self" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"docArtMag" : {
  "href" : "#"
}
  }
} ]
  },
  "_links" : {
"first" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"self" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"next" : {
  "href" : "#"
},
"last" : {
  "href" : "#"
}
  },
"page" : {
"size" : 10,
"totalElements" : 35078,
"totalPages" : 3508,
"number" : 0
}
}
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо

Comment: @АлексейФёдоров Не за что. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

Получение javascript объекта из `json` строки не зависит от уровней вложенности. Главное, чтобы [json-строка была валидной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81).

**Основной метод в JS - `JSON.parse('{"стока":"json"}')`.**

Но если вам надо также получить значения свойств как дату (`replayDate` и `lastUpdate`) то вам нужно использовать второй необязательный аргумент метода `JSON.parse`, который является функцией `function(key, value)`:

```
// В js необходимо экранировать перенос строк обратным слешем
var jsonStr = ' \
{ \
  "_embedded" : { \
    "document" : [ \
      { \
        "businessId" : "18749116-1-56", \
        "dateReception" : "2017-08-16T22:18:56.772+0000", \
        "type" : "ARTMAG", \
        "sequence" : 367, \
        "replayDate" : "2017-08-18T05:23:44.362+0000", \
        "rejectsNumber" : 3, \
        "status" : 303, \
        "errorCode" : "OPI_1001", \
        "lastUpdate" : "2017-08-17T22:52:36.522+0000", \
        "_links" : { \
          "self" : { \
            "href" : "#" \
          }, \
          "docArtMag" : { \
            "href" : "#" \
          } \
        } \
      }, \
      { \
        "businessId" : "18749116-1-79", \
        "dateReception" : "2017-08-16T22:18:56.756+0000", \
        "type" : "ARTMAG", \
        "sequence" : 367, \
        "replayDate" : "2017-08-18T05:23:44.370+0000", \
        "rejectsNumber" : 3, \
        "status" : 303, \
        "errorCode" : "OPI_1001", \
        "lastUpdate" : "2017-08-17T22:52:36.541+0000", \
        "_links" : { \
          "self" : { \
            "href" : "#" \
          }, \
          "docArtMag" : { \
            "href" : "#" \
          } \
        } \
      } \
    ] \
  }, \
  "_links" : { \
    "first" : { \
      "href" : "#" \
    }, \
    "self" : { \
      "href" : "#" \
    }, \
    "next" : { \
      "href" : "#" \
    }, \
    "last" : { \
      "href" : "#" \
    } \
  }, \
  "page" : { \
    "size" : 10, \
    "totalElements" : 35078, \
    "totalPages" : 3508, \
    "number" : 0 \
  } \
}';

// получим объект из json
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr, function(key,value){
  // Если ключ объекта - дата
  if (key == 'replayDate' || key == 'lastUpdate') {
    return new Date(value);
  }
  return value;
});

// получим поле с датой
console.log( obj._embedded.document[0].replayDate.getDate() );
// получим "глубокий" элемент
console.log( obj._embedded.document[0]._links.self.href )
```

Источник - [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/json#%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-json-parse-str-reviver)